# What is the most recent and stable version of Zen theme?

Tags: theming

I am searching for the most recent and stable version of the Zen theme.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does it say on the project page? https://www.drupal.org/project/zen

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7: 7.x-6.4 relased on 2016-06-04.

For Drupal 8 there are only alpha releases, most recent 8.x-7.0-alpha14 released on 2016-06-02.

See: https://www.drupal.org/project/zen (or https://www.drupal.org/project/zen/releases) and https://cgit.drupalcode.org/zen